# React-query doesn't refresh the component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I've got a problem with react-query. I've got a component which includes components that show a loading spinner if the integrationDetails query is fetching. But when the query finishes fetching, my component doesn't update at all. I tried creating state and then using that, but the problem persits.

UPDATE: The component does in fact update, but the child component  doesn't.

```
...

  const currentWorkspace = useGetCurrentWorkspaceDetail();
  const integrationDetails = useGetIntegrationDetails();
  useEffect(() => {
    integrationDetails.refetch(); //force refetch the query whenever I enter the page.
//problem persists even if I comment this part out
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(integrationDetails.isFetching); //this logs true and then false.
  }, [integrationDetails]);

  if (currentWorkspace.isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.layout}>
        <LoadingSpinner />
      </div>
    );
  }


  return (
    <div className={styles.layout}>
      <div className={styles.rest}>
        <div className={styles.column}>
          <Card>
            <CardTabs tabs={["1"]}>
              <div>
                <h3>Global Tracking Code</h3>
                <div style={{ marginTop: 12 }}>
                  <StatusStripe
                    isLoading={integrationDetails.isFetching}
                    ...
                  />
                </div>
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first useEffect would be just like `componentDidMount` and it will only be called on first render as you have passed an empty list i.e `[]` in its second argument.
You could have written your logic in your second useEffect where you know when the data is fetched and you can do your state setting or binding there.

Comment: Yes, that is the point of that first useEffect, to act like a `componentDidMount` and "force refetch" the query.

Comment: In your first question you are saying that when query finishes fetching results your component doesn’t update. Why are you trying to refetch that in componentDidMount when you have already added fetch hook. This still doesn’t make sense. If you child is not getting re-rendered then obviously that means that props you are passing to that components are not changing. You might also look your caching policy you’ve added for your query. May you can try network-only or no-cache as your cache policy.

Comment: The props I am passing down are changing as I checked that in the second use effect hook as well as just displaying it as a text in the component. Everything changes except the child component.

Comment: you need to show what your custom hooks are doing please, otherwise, its impossible to tell. It shouldn't be necessary to call `refetch` in an effect - that's what `refetchOnMount` will do for you (the flag is true per default) if your query is stale, so unless you've set a different staleTime or turned off that flag, it shouldn't be needed.